# Submitting answers to closed questions

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I have no idea how it happened, but I seem to have gained demi-god powers:

[image: what I did]

I started composing the answer before the question got closed and got distracted, so it took a while. Is this a new feature? If not, may I keep my new pet nonetheless? Because it is quite unnerving seeing the "this question has been closed, no answers can be submitted" banner after you've spent half an hour researching links and cropping pics for an answer and someone has considered it to be a bad fit in the meantime.

Edit: this appears to [affect "deleted" answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/537148/76595?noredirect=1) as well:

[image]

The odd side effect in case of migrations is that the migration destination copy will not be updated with the late edits.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed

Comment: @Iain this is so cool, what Javascript lines do I need to block to enable it permanently? :)

Comment: Erm ... dunno <>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working as (oddly) designed.

[How was this answer posted after this question was closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed)

Client-side validation trusts the client to validate it correctly. Sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Does it mean that *anyone* could submit answers to a closed questions within 4 hours after closure by crafting an appropriate POST request?

Comment: @syneticon-dj Prrrrrrrobably. Stop haxing the system!

Comment: @voretaq7 I never would even *think* of stopping.